# Angular CSS Component, como puedo cargar un componente con una hoja de estilos propia sin que interfiera la hoja de estilos global de styles.css

Tags: css, angular, script, aplicación-web

Tengo un problema con una aplicacion angular, quiero utilizar ngx-markdown para mostrar texto enriquecido en mi app siguiendo el siguiente ejemplo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-markdown
Me crea la estructura en html pero el problema viene con la hoja de estilos que tiene la aplicacion, esta pisando todo las clases de CSS.
Aplica la herencia de CSS, inherit y si lo deshabilito del navegador chrome se muestra como deberia.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Prueba agregando `!important;` al final de tu instrucción

Comment: En algunos casos, es necesario detener y volver a iniciar la aplicación angular porque no reconoce del todo las clases CSS

Comment: No puedo poner !importante; al CSS donde se esta componente xq es un componente de npm y tendría que editar en la carpeta node modules el paquete el archivo de CSS

Comment: Si intente reiniciar la ejecución del ng server y nada

Comment: prueba con las ngClass o metodos para manipular clase de Angular

Comment: si funciona manipulando cada clase, el problema es q tendria q reescribir todo el componente que esta en la carpeta node_modules, o copiar su CSS a mi componente y es un poco extenso.

Comment: intente crear un archivo module para el componente para cargar solamente lo de angular ni otro componente de node modules y otro paquete npm para q no se mezclen los CSS, voy a tener q plantearme en modificar en como se estan importando los modulos en cada componente